# How to set Admob ads refresh rate to Native express ads?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, admob

I have implemented `AdMob Native Express` `Adview` into my `RecyclerView`. I have also set **30 seconds** ads refreshing rate  to that `Adview`, but still ads are not going to refresh while scrolling​.

Answer (score 1):

Refresh rate is disabled by default for native ads. Native ads should complement the content and environment surrounding them. Refreshing native ads regularly may interfere with the look, feel, and cohesiveness of an app.